# How to get jQuery Mobile to use Javascript Array

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have jQuery mobile app. I get new data from the server and hold it in javascript Arrays.

When I go to a page in the jQuery mobile app I want it to populate with the data from the Javascript Arrays.

The reason for this is I update the data in the web app

Question is how do you put the Arrays on to the page and how do you call that function when the page is displayed.

I have tried jQuery.each but do not know when or how the function this is in is called.

Comment: This is really hard to decipher.  `this` isn't a function within `jQuery.each`.  Instead, it refers to each element of the array.  I'm not sure if that will help.  You can try using `console.log` on the `this` variable in `jQuery.each` and perhaps that will clear things up.  It's unclear what you mean by "put the Arrays on the page" though since arrays are not DOM elements.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Are you using JSON or some custom approach?

Comment: You are a long way away... First google/bing on how to use `jQuery.get()` since I believe you want to get the arrays from the server to the client, and then display them on success or whatever with `$.each()`.

Comment: I use jQuery.each to go through the array to look at each element.  That works I have tested with ALERT function   My server is App Engine  an I put out javascript which I read using jQuery.get and execut the result to load the javascript arrays. Works tested with ALERT.  I now want to put the data ( Javascript Array) on to the page withing my jQuery mobile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use arrays in my jquery mobile app like this:

For putting JSON data in an array:

```
    var g_RunCard = new Array();

    function fLoadRunCard() {
        $.getJSON("runCards.json", function (json) {
            g_RunCard = json;
        });
    }
```

I have code that uses the g_RunCard as needed.

Comment: How do you take the data from the array and show it on the web page. I am trying document.write but that overwrites everything.

Comment: I don't use document.write.  I had a <div> with a list and in the javascript, I do a $(#myId).append('<li>' + g_RunCard[card].Config[i] + '<li>');

Comment: For clarity, are you using JQuery to build a mobile app or are your using JQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/)?

Comment: I am using jquerymobile.com to format the app display. To write/call the server I am using jQuery.get and jQuery.post etc.  Just thinking if I used $.get etc is there a difference?